# ISC DHCP client (dhclient) alternative?

Tags: debian, dhcp, dhclient, debian-bullseye

I've just seen the news on https://www.isc.org/dhcp :

> ISC has ended development on the ISC DHCP client as of early 2022. This client implementation is no longer maintained and should not be used in production any longer.

**Now that `dhclient` seems to be retired, what DHCP client should I use?**

More specifically, I use Debian 11 and I need a DHCP client that can be instructed from the command line to renew the lease. Currently I do this:

```
sudo dhclient -r
sudo dhclient
```

Or, for a specific interface, like `eth0`:

```
sudo dhclient -r eth0
sudo dhclient eth0
```

**--- EDIT ---**

Other discussions of this question:

- https://groups.google.com/g/linux.debian.user/c/FSEkTKp3zEg
- https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2021/09/msg00407.html

They seem to suggest `systemd-networkd`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced dhclient with systemd-networkd's DHCP client the following way:

**1.** Uninstall dhclient

```
sudo apt purge -y isc-dhcp-client
sudo apt purge -y isc-dhcp-common
```

**2.** Start systemd-networkd

```
sudo systemctl start systemd-networkd
sudo systemctl enable systemd-networkd
```

**3.** Make systemd-networkd manage network interfaces, using its own DHCP client

For every interface, create a `*.network` config file in `/etc/systemd/network`, for example `05-enp1s0.network`:

```ini
[Match]
Name=enp1s0

[Network]
DHCP=yes
```

After restarting Linux, or restarting systemd-networkd, or `sudo networkctl reload`, these interfaces will be configured by the DHCP client of systemd-networkd. Renewing interface configurations is easy, for example:

```
sudo networkctl renew enp1s0
```

*This is highly subjective, but my initial experience is that systemd-networkd's DHCP client is more trustworthy and reacts faster than dhclient. If I change network connections, which happens often in my use case, I get a nice plug'n'play experience.*

---

**4. [Optional]** Add 8.8.8.8 as the primary DNS server

Turn on systemd-resolved:

```
sudo systemctl start systemd-resolved
sudo systemctl enable systemd-resolved
```

In `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`:

```ini
[Resolve]
DNS=8.8.8.8
```

In `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, add `resolve` at first place for `hosts`:

```
...
hosts:      resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] files dns
...
```

Now `systemd-resolve` will work, but `nslookup` will still use the DNS server that was written into `/etc/resolv.conf` by the DHCP client. To solve this, convert `/etc/resolv.conf` into a soft link to the resolv.conf file used by systemd-resolved:

```
cd /etc
sudo rm resolv.conf
sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf resolv.conf
```

After restarting systemd-resolved, this file contains 8.8.8.8 in the first line and below that the DNS servers collected by the DHCP client from the DHCP servers of connected networks, for example:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver 192.168.42.129
```

Comment: I identified the following legacy packages which concurrently interfere with a systemd-based network setup: `ifupdown` and `resolvconf`. I purged them away ... also notice that your answer currently recommends to create a symlink from `/etc/resolv.conf` to `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf`; whereas [`man 8 systemd-resolved.service`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-resolved.service.html#/etc/resolv.conf) recommends to symlink to `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf`.

Comment: @Abdull -- I think you are right regarding the symlink (see also: https://askubuntu.com/a/1154960), fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I just replaced isc-dhcp-client with udhcpc:

```
apt purge isc-dhcp-client udhcpc+
```

To renew (using the default of eth0):

```
udhcpc renew
```